# How is training of a face recognition system to detect faces done using Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: face-detection

In developing a face recognition we first need to detect faces.Recent way is to train a system on known databases i.e artificial intelligence and neural networks.I would like to know how this training is done?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Machine learning (both supervised and unsupervised), there's a lot of information on this available.

Comment: I really believe this is a cs.stack not here(but this wasn't an option in the flag

Comment: also maybe you should consider taking a shortcut and using face.com face recognition api (free for quite a lot queries per day)

Comment: Might be easier for you to get an answer in [cs theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: i have studied many training algorithms like adaboost and backpropagation.But i would love to know how they are implemented?What is the way to compile and run these algorithms?

Comment: actually you already asked the same question a couple of times and didn't bother to vote for an answer

Comment: @alonisser-i will certainly do so if i get some reasonble answer what i am looking for..n btw bzy in doing it.

Comment: The scope of this question is too broad. You should buy some book on face recognition and start from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When training your system, you will need to train a classifier to distinguish between faces and non-faces relying on a set of features.

These features can be defined differently, but for a simple approach, the whole array of pixels can be used as features. One pixel = one feature.

Then you would need to apply a training algorithm. Common ones are [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) and [support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine).

The training consists in correctly weighing the individual features to obtain the correct classification.

This can be done by minimizing a [cost function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_function#Optimization_algorithms).

You will need to separate your examples into at least two sets - the training set and the test set, to validate the results you get from training on a test set.